# Getting the index of a float in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

I have a dataset that I am pulling using pandas. It looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset=pd.read_csv('D:\\filename.csv', header=None, usecols=3,4,10,16,22,28])
time=dataset.iloc[:,0]
```

Now, the '`time`' dataset has a value of **0.00017** somewhere down the column and I want to find the index number of that location. How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're dealing with floats, you can't use an equality comparison here (because of floating point inaccuracies creeping in).

Use `np.isclose` + `np.argmax`:

```
idx = np.isclose(df['time'], 0.00017).argmax()
```

If there's a possibility this value may not exist:

```
m = np.isclose(df['time'], 0.00017)
if m.sum() > 0:
    idx = m.argmax()
```

Otherwise, set `idx` to whatever (`None`, `-1`, etc).

Comment: is there a way to do this to find the index values for multiple floating points, all in one go?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work if you have multiple columns with that floating value... it only shows the first instance that the value occurred.