# Is there a function to find the index of a float value in a column using pandas?

Tags: pandas, indexing

Hi so I have a dataframe `df` with a numeric index, a datetime column, and ozone concentrations, among several other columns. But here's a list of the important columns regarding my question.

```
index, date, ozone
0, 4-29-2018, 55.4375
1, 4-29-2018, 52.6375
2, 5-2-2018, 50.4128
3, 5-2-2018, 50.3
4, 5-3-2018, 50.3
5, 5-4-2018, 51.8845
```

I need to call the index value of a row based on the column value. However, multiple rows have a column value of 50.3. First, how do I find the index value based on a specific column value? I've tried:
`np.isclose(df['ozone'], 50.3).argmax()` from [Getting the index of a float in a column using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654661/getting-the-index-of-a-float-in-a-column-using-pandas)
but this only gives me the first index value that the number appears. Is there a way to call the index based on two parameters (like ask what the index value for when datetime = 5-2-2018 and ozone = 50.3)?

I've also tried df.loc but it doesn't work for floating points.

here's some sample code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('blah.csv')

df.set_index('date', inplace = True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
date = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
dv = df.groupby([date.month,date.day]).mean()
dv.drop(columns=['dir_5408'], inplace=True)

df['ozone'] = df.oz_3186.rolling('8H', min_periods=2).mean().shift(-4)
ozone = df.groupby([date.month,date.day])['ozone'].max()
df['T_mda8_3186'] = df.Temp_C_3186.rolling('8H', min_periods=2).mean().shift(-4)
T_mda8_3186 = df.groupby([date.month,date.day])['T_mda8_3186'].max()
df['T_mda8_5408'] = df.Temp_C_5408.rolling('8H', min_periods=2).mean().shift(-4)
T_mda8_5408 = df.groupby([date.month,date.day])['T_mda8_5408'].max()
df['ws_mda8_5408'] = df.ws_5408.rolling('8H', min_periods=2).mean().shift(-4)
ws_mda8_5408 = df.groupby([date.month,date.day])['ws_mda8_5408'].max()

dv_MDA8 = df.drop(columns=['Temp_C_3186', 'Temp_C_5408','dir_5408','ws_5408','u_5408','v_5408','rain(mm)_5724',
                       'rain(mm)_5408','rh_3186','rh_5408','pm10_5408','pm10_3186','pm25_5408','oz_3186'])
dv_MDA8.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

I need the date as a datetime index for the beginning of my code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You just need index values or the results from dataframe too ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might be looking for,

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({
'index':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
'date':['4-29-2018','4-29-2018','5-2-2018','5-2-2018','5-3-2018','5-4-2018'], 
'ozone':[55.4375,52.6375,50.4128,50.3,50.3,51.8845]
}
)
data.set_index(['index'],inplace=True)

data['date'] = data['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m- 
%d-%Y'))
data['ozone'] = data['ozone'].astype('float')

data.loc[(data['date'] == datetime.datetime.strptime('5-3-2018','%m-%d-%Y')) 
& (data['ozone'] == 50.3)]
```

[image]

Comment: just put df.index to get only index values at last line.

Comment: I tried `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')).date()` and keep getting the error message `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp`

Comment: have you paresrd it using `pandas.to_datetime()` or used something else ?

Comment: yes! Sorry I did not post much of my code, I thought it was going to be super simple. I'll update my post a bit.

Comment: no problem, I guess if you have already parsed your date column before then no need to perform that apply() method as it is just parsing string date to a timestamp. if you have used pandas.to_datetime() then you need to use same function inside your conditions too.

Answer (score 0):

Index represents each row and you can find out indexes and then store/use it
later until, ofcourse, the index of df has not changed

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

students = [('jack', 34, 'Sydeny', 'Engineering'),
            ('Sachin', 30, 'Delhi', 'Medical'),
            ('Aadi', 16, 'New York', 'Computer Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi', 'Data Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi', 'Data Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Mumbai', 'Information Security'),
            ('Aadi', 40, 'London', 'Arts'),
            ('Sachin', 30, 'Delhi', 'Medical')
            ]

df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City', 'Subject'])
print(df)

ind_name_sub = df.where((df.Name == 'Riti') & (df.Subject == 'Data Science')).dropna().index
# similarly you can have your ind_date_ozone may have one or more values
print(ind_name_sub)
print(df.loc[ind_name_sub])
```

Output:

```
     Name  Age      City               Subject
0    jack   34    Sydeny           Engineering
1  Sachin   30     Delhi               Medical
2    Aadi   16  New York      Computer Science
3    Riti   30     Delhi          Data Science
4    Riti   30     Delhi          Data Science
5    Riti   30    Mumbai  Information Security
6    Aadi   40    London                  Arts
7  Sachin   30     Delhi               Medical

Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64')

   Name  Age   City       Subject
3  Riti   30  Delhi  Data Science
4  Riti   30  Delhi  Data Science
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I replaced the code with my inputs:
`df.where((df.date == '2018-05-02 18:00:00') & (df.ozone == 50.3)).dropna().index`
and it gave me `Int64Index([], dtype='int64')`